# XPATH Expression help needed

Tags: xpath

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <nodeA>
   </nodeA>
   <nodeB>
       <nodeB></nodeB>
       <nodeB></nodeB>
       <nodeB></nodeB>
       <nodeB></nodeB>
   </nodeB>

   <nodeC>
   </nodeC>
</root>
```

I want to write an XPATH expression which will select the `<nodeB>` which is the parent of the other `<nodeB>` nodes.  I tried something like

"//nodeB/nodeB/parent::nodeB"

but it also choses `<nodeC>` besides the one I want.

Can you please help?

thanks
mc

Answer (score 1):

Try this (nodeB having a child of nodeB)

```
//nodeB[nodeB]
```